# Unit Test Failing during NavigationURL calls for Angular (8.3) Service implementing Router Navigation Event

Tags: angular, jasmine, navigation, router

I created a service which basically find the list of routes it navigate through. Below is the service which is working fine with the router navigationURL call within any component.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RoutingStateService {

  private routeHistory = [];

  constructor(
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  public loadRouting(): void {
    this.router.events
      .pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd))
      .subscribe(({urlAfterRedirects}: NavigationEnd) => {
        this.routeHistory = [...this.routeHistory, urlAfterRedirects];
      });
  }

  public getHistory(): string[] {
    return this.routeHistory;
  }

  public getPreviousUrl(): string {
    return this.routeHistory[this.routeHistory.length - 2] || '/index';
  }
}
```

It is being added to app.module to the providers and injected to the AppComponent

```
  constructor(routingState: RoutingStateService) {
    routingState.loadRouting();
    });
```

finally using them in the component fetching getPreviousURL

Below is the Unit test case I created. I am finding trouble with second unit test code for getHistory(). It always returning 0. I am expecting 2. I think I am missing some important points.

```
import { TestBed, inject, fakeAsync, flushMicrotasks } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { RoutingStateService } from './routing-state.service';
import { Router, NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

const routerStub = {
  events: from(
    [
      { urlAfterRedirects: 'path1' } as NavigationEnd,
      { urlAfterRedirects: 'path2' } as NavigationEnd
    ])
};

describe('RoutingStateService', () => {

  beforeEach(() => TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [RoutingStateService,
      { provide: Router, useValue: routerStub},
    ]
  }).compileComponents());

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: RoutingStateService = TestBed.get(RoutingStateService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should be created history', fakeAsync(
    inject([RoutingStateService], (service: RoutingStateService) => {
    service.loadRouting();
    flushMicrotasks();
    expect(service.getHistory().length).toEqual(2);
  })));
});
```

Comment: service.loadRoute() is async, because it calls subscribe(). So your expect() fires before your subscribe() finishes, which means you don't have any history yet.

Comment: I added Fakeasyn() considering this will handle the asyn call.